# MongoDB driver as a core module for connection pooling in Jboss

Tags: java, mongodb, jboss, datasource, jndi

Can anyone help me in configuring MongoDB driver as a core module for connection pooling in JBoss. Please refer to following step which I have tried after reading few posts.

1. Created a directory EAP_HOME/modules/com/mongodb/main/ and copy the mongodb-driver-3.4.0-rc1.jar (rc1 version because stable version 3.3.0 doesn't contain MongoClientFactory.class) and created module.xml file as below.

```html
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.mongodb">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="mongodb-driver-3.4.0-rc1.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

2. Then, Added MongoDB driver into standalone.xml file, please refer to the following properties I have added into standalone.xml file.

```html
<driver name="com.mongodb" module="com.mongodb">
  <xa-datasource-class>com.mongodb.client.jndi.MongoClientFactory</xa-datasource-class>
</driver>
```

After all these configuration I have started JBoss server and getting "Unable to find driver class name in "com.mongodb" jar" whereas jar is present and also contains MongoClientFactory datasource class.

Comment: did you solved this issue?

Comment: no @aelkz can you help

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a freeware solution to enable xa-datasource driver configuration.

Accordingly to Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 7 supported configurations, MongoDB isn't currently being supported:

https://access.redhat.com/articles/2026253

You can try these approaches below (using proprietary drivers):

1. https://www.progress.com/jdbc
2. http://www.unityjdbc.com/mongojdbc/mongo_jdbc.php (trial for 15 days)

However, you can try configuring a JNDI interface using MongoDB java driver:

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.3/driver/reference/connecting/jndi/#examples

"A MongoClient instance will be accessible via the JNDI name mongodb/MyMongoClient in the java:comp/env context."

Answering your question, maybe you'll need to put the *.jar inside this directory:

```
modules/system/layers/base/org/mongodb/main
```